# Interpretation of Parseval's identity in Euclidean space

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis

What would be the geometric or intuitive interpretation of Parseval's identity in the Euclidean space.
More specifically, what is the implication in any finite dimensional  inner product space with orthonormal bases.

Just want to go beyond looking at the proof of Parseval's identity to what does this actually tells us.

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the textbooks I used they reserve the name of Parseval's Identity for the case of Infinite Dimensional Hilbert Spaces so I actually assumed that you were referring to the "weak" identity for the finite dimensional case that you may be naming Parseval's Identity too (I actually have seen it as Bessel's Equality or even Parseval's Identity for the infinite dimensional is used just for the particular case of $L^2(-\pi,\pi)$).

It could be seen as a generalization of the Pythagora's Theorem. Let's consider $\mathbb{R}^2$ with the canonical basis (in particular it is an orthonormal basis). We know that for any $\textbf{x} \in \mathbb{R}^2$ we can write it as a linear combination of elements of the basis i.e. $\textbf{x}=(x_1,x_2)=x_1 \textbf{e}_1 + x_2 \textbf{e}_2$. Pythagora's Theorem tells us:

$$||\textbf{x}||^2=||x_1 \textbf{e}_1 + x_2 \textbf{e}_2||^2=x_1^2+x_2^2$$

Compare this with Parseval's Identity for $n=2$ . I think the extension for higher dimensions or spaces with a different inner product than the canonical one is pretty straightforward but feel free to ask anything (or point out any mistake or sloppy reasoning there may be).

Comment: @Pantizanki Thank you. These were my thoughts but needed broader perspective to see if they were in order.

Comment: @Pantizakis perhaps the norm of x would need to be squared ?  So that the equation becomes less ambiguous (w.r.t inner product space).

Comment: @snoopy oops, you are absolutely right, fixed it, thank you!